# Static Checker not proving parameters != null

Tags: c#, code-contracts

When I learned about Code Contracts, I assumed I could do the following:

```
public void ContractTest(string input)
{
    Contract.Requires(input != null);
}

public void ContractTestCaller(string input)
{
    this.ContractTest(input);
}
```

And get a warning since it is not possible to prove `input != null` in `ContractTestCaller`. However I don't get a warning.
Then I thought I might at least get a warning when I do this:

```
public void ContractTestCallerCaller()
{
    this.ContractTestCaller(null);
}
```

But again, nothing.

I see three different possibilites:

1. I'm doing something wrong.
2. Code Contracts is not supposed to do this.
3. The static checker is just not very good.

Which one is it?

Here are my settings:

[image]

Comment: Check your contract settings in Visual Studio, its in the project properties. Depending on the build settings they can actually be omitted during compilation.

Comment: @Dandré I added my settings. I think they are right, though because I get other code contract warnings. I just assumed I would get one here as well.

Comment: Can you add the class definitions? I'm pretty sure code contracts require attributes to function correctly.

Comment: @Eris I did not use any. Which one should I add?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx has an example at the end of the page.

Comment: @Eris No other article I found mentios this. Weird.

Comment: @Eris After a bit of research, I come to the conclusion that you only need those attributes if you have your contracts in a seperate class. Also note that I get warnings if I do something more obvious as `ContractTest(null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is the "Infer Requires" option being checked. I do not completely understand why but it works when I turn it off.

I also found this link refering to the same problem:
https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/439